# A controller method is not called

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I wrote some jQuery script for my site so my controller method will be executed - well, the method is not even called. It seems as everything works properly except that the controller method wasn't even called.

Here is my relevant code - the button itself:

```
<a href="#" data-id="@product.Id" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" style="margin-left:60px">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add to cart
</a><br />
```

The jQuery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".btn.btn-info.btn-lg").click(function(event)
{
      event.preventDefault();
      var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart", new {idinput = "IDI",amount="AM"}))';
      url = url.replace("AM", $("#amounter").val());
      url = url.replace("IDI", $(this).data("id"));

      window.location.href = url;
});
</script>
```

Note that I have the following controller method inside controller named `CartController` file:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCart(int idinput, int amount)
```

Once I press the button, I reach:

```
http://localhost:59463/Cart/AddToCart?idinput=1&amount=44
```

Well, I am not sure how should it work, but the controller method is not even called..

Comment: You can't `GET` an action with `HttpPost` attribute on it...

Comment: @DavidG thanks it helped (solved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action has the `HttpPost` attribute on it which means it will only respond to an HTTP `POST` request. If you just try to visit the URL using `window.location.href = url` it will perform an HTTP `GET` instead. So you will get a 404.

Remote the `[HttpPost]` attribute from the action or make your Javascript perform a     `POST` operation which is more semantically logical to "add" an item anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting by setting `window.location.href` which is a `GET` operation. Your controller expects `POST`. You should do a form post or some ajax to add it. `GET` is not a good way to add things to carts.

Answer (score 0):

Complete Solution

```
function AddToCart() {
        var url = "@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart")";
        var idinput = $("#idinput").val();
        var amount = $("#amount").val();
        var rate = {
            idinput: idinput,
            amount: amount
        };
        rate = JSON.stringify(rate);
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=iso-8859-1",
        data: rate
      });
    }
public ActionResult AddToCart(Data Data)
{
   return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
public class Data
    {
        public int idinput { get; set; }
        public int amount { get; set; }
    }
```